# Mule invoking database connector from cxf soap service to call multple stored procedure in each method

Tags: web-services, mule, mule-component

Can you please help me and provide any example or scenario in which I can invoke db call using flow from web service operation. if my web service implementation have five operations and each operation has to call a separate query or stored procedure.

I have the other way around by injecting database template using spring injection and call the required query or stored procedure but I want to do it with flows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at CXF proxy service:https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/proxying-web-services-with-cxf

It allows to access the raw SOAP message and route it how you wish, such as using a choice router using Xpath on the operation name, or you could extract the SOAPAction header etc.

```
<flow name="soap-api" doc:name="soap-api-orders">
        <https:.... />

        <cxf:proxy-service payload="body"
            service="MyService-v1c" namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/MyService"
            wsdlLocation="wsdl/MyService.wsdl" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false"
            doc:name="CXF" />


        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when
                expression="#[xpath('boolean(//mynamespace:MyOperation1/node()[1])')]">
                <flow-ref name="flow1" />
            </when>
            <when
                expression="#[xpath('boolean(//mynamespace:MyOperation2/node()[1])')]">
                <flow-ref name="flow2"  />
            </when>
            <otherwise>

            </otherwise>
        </choice>
</flow>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
What do you think of the approach in which you provide the java component and in java component set some variable to distinguish the operation and continue the flow using choice router to db nodes.